# How to test Handsontable with virtual scrolling in Angular App using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests, handsontable

We use [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com) in a hybrid AngularJS / Angular app that we test using Protractor. As far as I know we don't use the available Angular wrapper for Handsontable but instead use it directly.

Typical actions we would like to do in a fast way:

- Expand all collapsed columns in the table
- Read value of cell (x,y)
- Read all values in row y
- Change the value in cell (x,y)

Currently we have two approaches to test Handsontable components:

- Using regular CSS selectors to find elements. This is pretty fast. But it only works if the table has no virtual scrolling, so that all elements are actually in the DOM.
- **Using keyboard navigation (up, down, left, right). This also works with virtual scrolling, but it's very slow.**

Do you know any other approaches that can speed up tests especially for larger tables with virtual scrolling? Is there maybe some way to talk to the Handsontable API *directly from the Protractor test* to scroll / select a certain cell in a table that has virtual scrolling?

Comment: I know it's an old post, but worth a shot, since I have a similar question.  @Adrian could you share concerning your keyboard navigation tests, specifically, how what code are you using to read value of cell (x,y)?

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to this codebase anymore, so I can't share any details.